# Everytime Camera dismiss, Viewdidload got called

Tags: iphone, camera, viewcontroller, iphone-3gs

it happens only on the 3GS, 4 or 3G is OK.

seems like viewcontroller got called everytime camera dismissed.

any thoughts on that?

It's Iphone, the system calls viewdidunload my view of viewcontroller when I did a

[self presentModalViewController:picker1 animated:YES];

I don't want the system to dismiss my view.  I did a [self.view retain] but that doesn't help.

Comment: some thoughts are: What camera? What libraries? What's the problem? Could you add some more information so that we can help you?

Comment: @shamster: Seems like Iphone.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` can be called multiple times.  If the iPhone needs memory, it will release the view and then rebuild it the next time it has to show it.  This is normal -- you cannot count on only a single call.  You should get a `viewDidUnload` call before it's called again.

Comment: I try to retain the view of the viewcontroller by [self.view retain];but when camera presentmodalview the system calls viewdidunload. How can I prevent the view of viewcontroller from taken out?

Comment: You cannot. You need to save the state of all UIs, e.g. the text in UITextField, restore them when requested.